# Fail to addObject to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am building this 'Add to favorite' with NSUserDefault. I am having this issue when adding array to NSMutableArray. Does anyone knows what I did wrong? Thank you very much.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *favoriteRecipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


if ([prefs objectForKey:@"myFavor"] == nil) {
    //create the array
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [prefs setObject:array forKey:@"myFavor"];
    [array release];
}
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[prefs objectForKey:@"myFavor"] mutableCopy];
favoriteRecipes = tempArray;
[tempArray release];

NSArray *charArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test1", @"test2" , nil];

//add the recipe
[favoriteRecipes addObject:[charArray objectAtIndex:0]];  

//save the array to NSUserDefaults
[prefs setObject:favoriteRecipes forKey:@"myFavor"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Comment: I am confused,you are getting run time error or not able to get desired result you expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
favoriteRecipes = tempArray;

instated of above line use be below line it will work fine 

[favoriteRecipes addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
```

Comment: Thank you. it works, although I don't know why. It should be no different than what I did.

Comment: I have another similar problem again. Here is my error message: 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance '

Comment: My Script:                                                          - (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSMutableArray *titleArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"myFavor1"] mutableCopy]; self.dataArray = titleArray; self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES; self.deleteButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButton; [self resetUI]; }

Answer (score 0):

done something like this yesterday. see my code below. im not sure if you want the same thing like I did.

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:productID,@"ID",productTitle,@"title",productPrice,@"price",imageUrl,@"image",shipping,@"shipping_day", nil];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *cartList = [[defaults objectForKey:@"CART_ITEMS"] mutableCopy];

if(!cartList)
    cartList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if([cartList indexOfObject:tempDictionary] == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"add favorite");
    [cartList addObject:tempDictionary];
    [defaults setObject:cartList forKey:@"CART_ITEMS"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [sender setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"remove favorite");
    [cartList removeObject:tempDictionary];
    [defaults setObject:cartList forKey:@"CART_ITEMS"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [sender setTitle:@"Add to cart" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
}
```

this is what I do everytime I want my favorite list from NSUserDefault

```
-(void)getCartList
{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *cartList = [[defaults objectForKey:@"CART_ITEMS"] mutableCopy];
productListArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:cartList];
NSLog(@"cart list data == %@", cartList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me. I got 'Save' working. but problem with the 'Retrieve'. It's very similar like your 'getCartList()'. However, I got run time error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: where and how do you get that exception?

Comment: my NSMUtableArray contains NSDictionary "tempDictionary", this is how I assign data to cell objects.

[cell.textLabel setText: [productListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text_key"]];

Comment: I give up to get my script working. I am modifying and using your example now. It seems working great. A big thank to you for sharing.

Comment: I am sorry to bother again. how do you handle the delete from your productListArry? I created a delete button. but don't know how to script to remove object

Comment: see my code I posted in my answer. the code inside else deletes the object